# Topology of the intersection of two topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

If we are given two topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$. Then obviously we can form the set
$X\cap Y$ as the set of elements which belong to both $X$ and $Y$. My question is are we allowed to talk about the topological space $X\cap Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are not subsets of a third space $Z$? and if yes what is the topology we usually put on $X\cap Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are not subsets of a third space $Z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *usually* as this is not commonly done.

Yes, if both $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces of a common space $Z$ and their topology is the subspace topology wrt that $Z$. In that case, the topology on $X \cap Y$ is just the subspace topology of that $X \cap Y$ wrt that same $Z$, and $X \cap Y$ will also have the subspace topology wrt $X$ and $Y$, as everything is coherent and initial topologies are transitive.

If there is no relation like that such things are not done unless in the case of $Y=X$, so two topologies on the same set. (There even is such a thing as a bitopological space, a space with two topologies on it).

Comment: Ok I understand, I'm asking because this is done for the union. We put the coherent topology on the union $X\cup Y$  without $X$ or $Y$ being subsets of a third space. I thought something similar could be done for the intersection.

Comment: @palio In a union that is disjoint there is no conflict: every point has its own set of neighbourhoods. But in an intersection, how would we choose between two conflicting sets of neighbourhoods? only the common ones might lose to much of the structure e.g.